# Reading txt file in python using list comprehension

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

How can I return in python a word which has the same length as a word searched. For example, I am looking for a closest match for the word "three" in a list of ["three","tea","tree"] and I want to return the first occurence of the same length word.

I need to do it using generator or some list comprehensions as I have a really big set of data. Until now I have this function:

```
matches_list= dl.get_close_matches(word.lower(),list_of_words)
if matches_list:
      new_word= (w for w in matches_list if (len(word)==len(w)))  
      print new_word.next()
```

Which prints just fine until the 4th or 5th iteration where I get this message error:

```
print new_word.next()
StopIteration
```

Comment: `StopIteration` just means that you've reached the last item in your generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) and supply a default:

```
new_word = (w for w in matches_list if len(word) == len(w))  
print next(new_word, 'nothing found')
```

The `StopIteration` exception is raised because your generator reached the end without a (further) match. If you give a second argument to the `next()` function, then it'll catch that exception and return that second argument as a default instead.